# simulating POP3 mail server for automation service

Tags: c#, .net, node.js, automation, integration-testing

I have a service that receive mail messages from a provider and my service handle this mail messages (parse the mail message, download attachments, handle attachments etc.).

I would like to create automation end 2 end tests for this service at integration level.

For example I would like to be able to order my automation service:

```
service.PrepareMailMessages(numberOfMessages);
service.LoadMailMessagesToServer(numberOfMessages);

service.HandleMailMessages();
....
service.ValidateResults();
```

In order to do this, I'll need to have local mail server (I don't want to use my organization mail server) that will provide my services (maybe `Node.JS`, but I didn't find souitable package for this kind of task).

To sum up I need mail server that will enable me to:

1. Load pre-prepare messages to the server.
2. Fetch the already defined messages from my code and handle it.

Are you familiar with a framework that will enable me to do so?